# cygwin mirrors/ repositories - tee and svn

Tags: svn, cygwin, mirroring, repository, tee

I have run Cygwin setup using a handful of different repositories, but certain programs appear to be missing from from the ones I have tried so far. I am specifically looking for *tee* and *svn*.

Which repositories/ mirrors are complete?

Comment: Why would you want svn under Cygwin?

Comment: @Ignacio What alternative would you suggest? (CLI,not GUI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Cygwin Package List](http://cygwin.com/packages/) to find the appropriate packages.

The latest version of Cygwin includes /bin/tee as part of coreutils.

http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=%2Fbin%2Ftee

And svn aka Subversion is found in the self named package.

http://cygwin.com/packages/subversion/

If you're not finding these packages listed in your mirrors, you're not running the latest version of Cygwin.

Comment: Another way to find the `tee` executable is to search for `tee.exe`.